# How to exclude specific dependency from spring-boot-starter-parent

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I am using a Spring boot application. Spring boot parent dependency coming up with lot of legacy versions of (plexus-utils). I need to use specific version of (plexus-utils).

I have tried adding below code in properties tag of my pom.xml but no luck its still downloading legacy vesions like `(1.5.8, 3.0.10, 2.1, 1.5.5..)`. I have tried adding both versions (1. plexus-utils and 2. codeahus) to see either one works.

```
    <properties>
    <plexus-utils.version>3.5.1</plexus-utils.version>
    <codehaus.version>3.5.1</codehaus.version>
    </properties>
```

I need to do changes such that spring boot parent needs to download only `3.5.1` version. Below is pom.xml. Can anyone please assist me here, is there any alternative we need to exclude or something needs to be corrected in my properties tag code ?

```
   <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.6</version>
    <relativePath />
  </parent>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
        <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
   <dependencies>
```

Comment: You should check which maven plugin versions are being used... and you should define them all your self to be sure the most recent versions will be used (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/) ... defining things like plexus-utils as a dependencies will not help here...

Comment: Are you using eclipse?

Comment: Thanks. @khmarbaise  the problem is with Maven plugins and I have resolved it by overriding it.

Answer (score 1):

First I started debugging the code with maven compile to see which plugin/dependency is downloading the vulnerable versions.

Then I went through this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/mvn-plugin-dependency-exclusion)
I have made below changes to my maven plugins, that's it. It worked.

***NOTE***: If you don't specify any specific versions from you're pom.xml. Maven downloads the defaults plugins with help of (whatever maven version is update in maven_home)

```
         <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                        <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
                        <version>3.5.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                        <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
                        <version>3.5.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: The dependency to plexus utils should not be neccessary... defining the plugins itself must be enough...

Comment: @khmarbaise - My objective is to override the plexus utils packages which are coming with maven plugins.

Comment: Why is it needed to override the version? The problem is that you are using the spring-boot-parent ... which contains plugin versions which are not up-to-date... you can define them on your own...

Answer (score 0):

just add </> to your pom.xml file.
`<exclusions> <groupid> <artifcatid> </>`

basically consider this as telling mvn or any other build tool to exclude this dependency.

Comment: accordingly add your groupid and artifactid for your dependency that you want to exclude.

Comment: My issue is with plugins, not with dependencies.

Comment: You can use  <pluginManagement> tag in pom xml file. Within the <pluginManagement> section and then use <exclusion> tag. Inside <plugin> use <exclusions> for any plugin you want to exclude. Reference here: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html for examples.